# PixiJX fill object inner space

Tags: pixi.js

I'm using PixiJS to assembly some complex image consisting of background, texts and images, like this:

[image: What I have.]

So I create one sprite from background image, add text object and then other image from file, then place all things to the stage. I need to fill image transparent areas with solid color:

[image: What I want.]

Image can vary both by size and shape, so I can't use separate image for its background, and it comes from external source and I am not able to edit it manually.

How can I do it?

Comment: i have the same problem, bro